# Woocommerce Custom Checkout Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a custom checkout field, but I would like for it to react dynamically with the Shipping/Billing Country dropdown.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
global $woocommerce;
$ship_country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
    if ($ship_country !== 'US'){
    $fields['billing']['international_catalogue'] = array(
        'label'     => __('I would like to receive a catalogue', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'default'   => 0
             );
         }
 $fields['billing']['email_opt_out'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Please send me the monthly newsletter <BR>(You can unsubscribe at any time)', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'type'      => 'checkbox',
    'class'     => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'default'   => 1
         );

 return $fields;
}
```

This only works the way I want if you reload the checkout page after changing the Country.  How do I get this checkbox to react dynamically?

Comment: Use jquery to dynamically update

Comment: This won't work, because PHP is a server-side language. It can't dynamically add fields to a form without reloading the page. You need to add the field as a hidden input (always), but hide it with JavaScript, unless the user selects US.